# Is there anyway to run only selected code in Java Eclipse?

Tags: java

Is there anyway that I can run only part of the code which I select, instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> and execute all?

Comment: do you mean selected java file?

Comment: Since the java compiler does only invoke code from a main method, no.

Comment: Add more `main()` methods or via unit test.

Comment: You can debug it to have it run on a certain point,

Comment: No, I mean selected text. I wanna test the result of the first half of the code without copying it to a new class and run it.

Comment: Yeah you can debug it. Just select the line for the breakpoint and it will run the good up to that point.

Comment: OK thank you, I got it. Btw the debug will run from the beginning? Is there anyway that I can set the break point before and after the code that I wanna test?

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking, but yes it will run from the beginning like a normal run, but stop at the breakpoint. You can go in the the debug prospective and check all of variable values. Really handy stuff.

Comment: Put a debug point to start and end code chunk then press `F6`.

Answer (score 3):

No. There is no way to run only part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily test a part of your code through a junit test.

- get JUnit
- add the annotation @Test on the method you want to test
- left click on the method => debug as... => JUnit test

You probably need to mock the database calls

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse you can create a "Scrapbook Page" to test pieces of codes.

In Eclipse go to:

```
File -> New -> Scrapbook Page -> "MyScrapbook"
```

Eclipse will create a file "MyScrapbook.jpage"

Write the code in the file, don't create class or main.

Select the piece of code you have wrote and want to run, and press CTRL+U

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to test a method without any context, you could try using the groovy console and copy / paste there the code you want to "test". You will be able to run it and "test" it.

A link to it : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Groovy/article.html

Otherwise the only way to do it is to go through traditional debug mode.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Ah the Groovy Console is a kind of REPL program, right?

Comment: Kind of yes ! You can paste come code and execute it directly !

Answer (score 0):

You can absolutely run part of your code (in Eclipse). Just use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + click to select the parts you do not want to run, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> to comment out huge bits of code quickly.

To uncomment, make sure you select continuous sections of vertical `//`'s, and then use the same <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> command to quickly get rid of all the `//`'s.

**Note:** if you press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> with code selected, you will get the "block comment" (`/* code not running */"-type). Use the same keys to undo it, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>.

For me, it is less easy to locate those quickly versus the massive vertical line of `//`'s

Comment: That technically modifies the code though. Its not like it would be a feature of the IDE to only execute selected parts.

Comment: @zabuzard I get that... It is just a work around to actually run a line of code (again, in eclipse). If the question was how to do so without temporarily modifying the code I would've left it as is, but I had the same question and didn't get it to work on the console, and I also didn't want to do the second or third options: deleting everything but the code you're checking, or...creating a new java project to copy the lines to check into.... at this point I don't know but that was just my solution :)